# Using flalign in lyx

Tags: align

I want to write in LyX "lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=5":

[image]

But I want the "n\to\infty" to be right under the "lim". Not in subscript. I know I could do by pressing ctrl+shift+m instead of ctrl+m when opening the equation, but I want it to be left-aligned.

How do I do it?

Comment: I believe that amsmath has a package option for that.

Comment: There's [math operators - LyX and Summation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104107/lyx-and-summation) although I didn't try the solutions. Or [math mode - Default Display-Like Style for Mathematics in LyX Instead of Inline - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341203/default-display-like-style-for-mathematics-in-lyx-instead-of-inline).

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=5$`.